# Only first image stays in view when browser size decreases

Tags: css, html, size, image-resizing

I have a series of images laid across horizontally in a div.

The goal is that as the browser gets smaller, so do the images, so they are all visible and stay inline.

Currently, only the first image will stay visible, while the other images go out of view. (Although all of the images to get smaller.

Here is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KXGUM/

You will notice that one you make your browser smaller, the images will get smaller but only the first one will stay in view, the others you have to scroll right to see.

I want all of them to still be visible, meaning they all have to shrink together.

CSS:

```
body{margin: 0 auto;}
#week-wrap {border: 1px solid #000; height: auto; white-space: nowrap; max-width: 100%; width: auto; }
img {max-width: 100%; height: auto; display: inline-block; width: auto;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you got 3 images their width should be 33% of the parent container. 
Change your 100% in 33% and they're all on the screen and in one line.

```
img {max-width: 33%; height: auto; display: inline-block; width: auto;}
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/KXGUM/1/